# Obj. C - how to deal with wrong written JSON

Tags: ios, json, web-services

I obtained some badly written JSON file that's totally not readable through any AFNetworking and/or any other JSON serializing library. I must underline that I am not able to force to change it on server-side so I have to parse it as is.
Unfortunately it has some minor errors (I will paste small part of it):

```
locations = [{
    "city": "Tokio",
    (...)
    "link": "http://somethig.com",
    "text": "Mon-Fr.",
}, {
```

(... same repeated mistakes, but they're not regular)

```
 }]
```

Aaand to parse it correctly in XCode i need to change it to correct format e.g.:

```
{
    "locations": [{
        "city": "Tokio",
         (...)
        "link": "http://somethig.com",
        "text": "Mon-Fr."
    }, {
        (...)
}]
}
```

Do you have any idea how to deal with that?
If I will have to write my own parser - please advice me how to. Any help will be appreciated. I download this JSON from http link.

Comment: Sounds like you'll have to write code that removes trailing commas. Seems like a giant pain to detect when it's appropriate to remove them. Why can't you open a bug report with the API developer? If you really can't, maybe see if this API has any other clients who have already solved this problem. They might have an algorithm you can leverage.

Comment: It has been clearly said to me, that I have to use this API without changing it. Bad thing is that I thought that I was parsing it wrong and lost 1 work day on it. After claiming errors in JSON to boss, I've been told to "Write a parser to it, it is really easy. It's beginner task".

Comment: Trailing commas aren't your only problem; your original "JSON" looks like a variable assignment.  But that, like the trailing commas, is an easy thing to fix.

Comment: @ScottHunter, do You have any clues or resources how to perform this easy fix?

Comment: @ScottHunter Without a well-defined spec, I'm not sure it's easy.

Comment: Replacing `([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)w*=\w*` with `"\1":` looks pretty easy to me; then you have to put the enclosing `{}` and commas.  There might be other issues to complicate things, though.

Comment: @ScottHunter That might work if you *know* none of the strings will match the patterns. i.e. `locations = [{"equation": "2 + 2 = 4", …`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the API is sending you a string of JavaScript code. In JavaScript, you would use `JSON.stringify()` to convert the object to valid JSON. Here's an example from [an interactive node.js shell](http://nodeguide.com/beginner.html#hello-world-tutorial):

```
> locations = [{
...     "city": "Tokio",
...     "link": "http://somethig.com",
...     "text": "Mon-Fr.",
... }]
[ { city: 'Tokio', link: 'http://somethig.com', text: 'Mon-Fr.' } ]
> JSON.stringify(locations)
'[{"city":"Tokio","link":"http://somethig.com","text":"Mon-Fr."}]'
```

If you really can't change this on the server side, you might try creating a hidden `UIWebView`, adding the JavaScript, calling `JSON.stringify()`, and extracting the result. However, this will use many more resources than are needed. It would be much better (in terms of computing power, memory, and your time) to have the API call `JSON.stringify()` and send you a valid JSON string.

You could also try porting some of [json3.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.js) to Objective-C or Swift. I would start with the section beginning `` // Public: `JSON.stringify`. `` if you attempt this.

Comment: That sound good to me, so far. But It doesn't seem like "easy thing" for Obj C only junior dev :) I will try it at once!